# 还是付了吧，要不忘了。了 is ...?

Tags: usage

**还是付了吧，要不忘了**

This sentence probably means

That's exactly I'll pay for it , not to forget to do.

I know　了 has many aspects.

What's difference between "first 了" and "second 了"?

I think "first 了" is to draw a conclusion, and "second 了"　expresses just the time of forgetting to pay for it.

Is it not right?

Comment: Ah, i think it actually means :

Comment: We d better pay the bills right now, for fear of forgetting to pay when we leave.

Comment: You can think of 了 here as 'manage to'. Let's manage to pay the check now, or I might manage to forget before we leave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both denote the completion as defined in [this dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E86.htm):

> 放在动词或形容词后，表示动作或变化已经完成：写完～。

付了: get it paid; 忘了: forgotten it.

> 还是付了吧，要不忘了:
>
> 1. Better get it paid (now), or you/I would/might have forgotten (to pay it).
> 2. Better get it paid (now), in case you/I would/might have forgotten (to pay it).

Answer (score 1):

还是(better off)

付了吧，(pay it off)

要不(or else)

忘了 (forgotten)

> "还是付了吧，要不忘了" means "better off pay it off (now), or else (I might) forget"

- '了' in '付了' is a particle that indicate completion of the verb
- '了' in '忘了'  is a particle that indicate completion of the verb

付= to pay; 付了= to pay (and finish paying it up)

忘= to forget;  忘了= to forget (and actually/successfully forgotten)

Answer (score 1):

A natural translation would be:

> 还是付了吧，要不忘了
>   we'd better pay, otherwise we'll forget

Although of course there is no 我们 in the sentence, so we don't know if the speaker means "we" or "I" or "you". The context would make that clear.

The first 了 is a modal particle. It is NOT an aspect particle and it does NOT indicate completion of the verb. It indicates a change of state.

The second 了 is part of the word 忘了. You're better off just learning this as a compound word meaning "to forget", rather than worrying about the grammar of it.